# Could I represent any infinite digits sequence using finite formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, I have set of digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. I'm writing any sequence using any amounts of each digit. Then, I want to represent my sequence as a finite formula to send it to my friend. Could somebody finish it?

Comment: Does the sequence repeat in the number?

Comment: No, you can't.  This is the point of the existence of "non-computable" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could not represent any sequence of digits with a finite formula. The cardinal of the set of infinite digits sequence is $2^{\aleph_0}\geq\aleph_1$ and the cardinal of finite formulas is $\aleph_0$. So there is way too many sequences to stick a different formula on each.

Comment: No, it's $c=2^{\aleph_0}$, which may or may not equal $\aleph_1$. Look up "Continuum Hypothesis"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich isn’t $2^{\aleph_0}$ the cardinality of the reals between 0 and 1 (thing of binary digits). Which in turn is the cardinality of the whole reals and by definition $\aleph_1$. The continuum hypothesis doesn’t question the equality of this answer. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis

Comment: @alfC Yes, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of $[0,1]$. "by definition $\aleph_1$; What ??????

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich isn’t the cardinality of $[0, 1]$ precisely $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @alfC No. Or rather in some sense nobody knows; the question of whether $c=\aleph_1$ is not settled by the standard axioms of set theory. (This is the "continuum hypothesis". You mention CH in a comment above; given the current question I can't imagine what you think/thought CH _is_...)

Comment: Ok, but we all accept that $\aleph_1 >  \aleph_0$, no? and since the first the cardinality of "all sequences" and the second is the cardinality of "formulas". Isn't that enough to answer (negatively) the original question.